# How to generate signature in java and use it in jQuery (Cloudinary)?

Tags: java, jquery, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload images to Cloudinary using jQuery and Java. I tried the code in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019371/how-to-use-cloudinary-jquery-plugin-to-upload-images-directly-from-a-page) with no luck. I'm getting errors in generating the signature.
Does anyone have an example of a working implementation for generating the signature? That would be more helpful.

Comment: Sir,now i managed to upload and retrieve images successfully.my question is how to delete a uploaded image in jquery?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following code in your index.jsp:

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <script src='jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
            <script src='jquery.ui.widget.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
            <script src='jquery.iframe-transport.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
            <script src='jquery.fileupload.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
            <script src='jquery.cloudinary.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
            <script type = "text/javascript">
                $.cloudinary.config({ cloud_name: 'sample', api_key: '874837483274837'});
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input name="file" type="file" 
               class="cloudinary-fileupload" data-cloudinary-field="image_id" 
               data-form-data="${signedData}" />
        </body>
    </html>
```

If you have a maven project then place these dependencies in your pom.xml or else download their jars and place them in your 'lib' folder.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Finally create a Servlet as:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class SignRequestServlet extends HttpServlet{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequet request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

        long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
        String unsignedData = "&quot;api_key&quot;:&quot;874837483274837&quot;,&quot;timestamp&quot;:&quot;" + unixTime + "&quot;";
        String unsignedDataForSHA = "timestamp="+unixTime;
        String apiSecret = "-----place your api secret here-----";
        String unsignedDataSecret = unsignedDataForSHA + apiSecret;
        String signedData = unsignedData + ",&quot;signature&quot;:&quot;" + DigestUtils.shaHex(unsignedDataSecret.getBytes()) + "&quot";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{" + signedData.replaceAll("&quot;", "\"") + "}");

        request.setAttribute("signedData", jsonObject.toString());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequet request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

**Remember:** Replace the api-key, cloud-name and api-secret as given in the home page of Cloudinary console. Also, you may need to change the location of the .js files in index.jsp.

Comment: Thanks Asim it helps a lot

Comment: You made my code, I've just added: var codeSuccess = function(response) {
      var code = response.o
      $("#xxx").attr('data-form-data', code)
                   }
              $.getJSON(GET_CODE, codeSuccess)

Answer (score 0):

While Asim's answer is very appreciated, also note that Cloudinary's Java SDK already offers a helper method to generate the signature for you. Simply pass the params and you're done.
See the following for reference:
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_java/blob/master/cloudinary-core/src/main/java/com/cloudinary/Cloudinary.java#L133